# Does the Filemaker API implement caching for _find requests or portalData requests?

Tags: php, curl, filemaker

I am rewriting an application which uses a Filemaker database.  Historically, a PHP script had a PHP SDK connection to Filemaker.  I am converting it to use the Filemaker 17 API.

During development I am creating a new record, and then displaying a list of records.  After creating a new record, the old system (using the PHP SDK) will display the updated list immediately.  The new system I'm developing will not.

After a few minutes, the new system (using the Filemaker 17 API) will show the correct list.  It seems to take 5-10 minutes.

All of this is happening through the use of portals.

I'm using the Symfony PHP framework.  I've tried clearing the Symfony cache.

I've also tried appending a UNIX timestamp to the _find URL of the API call.  It still returns me a list, but it's a stale list.

I'm using the `'cache-control: no-cache'` cURL option, as well.

I've scoured the FM 17 API documentation, but can't find anything pertinent.

Is there a cache that the FM API implements?  If so, how do you disable that?

I expect the list to update immediately through the FM 17 API.

#### -- **Updated** --

If I manually update the *record* containing the portal data, the list returned from the API works instantly.  Is portal data cached?

Answer (score 1):

To ensure there is fresh data you could close the API session and start a new session.

> When your code is done accessing the hosted database, use an HTTP
>   DELETE method with the sessions URL specifying the name of the hosted
>   database and the access token for the session. If your code does not
>   log out of the database session, the access token becomes invalid when
>   the FileMaker Data API session times out 15 minutes after the last
>   call that specified the token.

https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/17/en/dataapi/index.html#write-fm-data-api-calls_connect-database_log-out

Or as part of your find you could run a script in the script.pre-request as part of your _find that will refresh the portals on the layout.  E.g. using the "Refresh Portal" script step. The "caching" behaviour that you see may just be that the layout is not updating for that Data API session, and the layout needs updating.

> You can run FileMaker scripts as part of the find request by including the
>   script.prerequest, script.presort, and script parameters in the
>   request body.

https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/17/en/dataapi/index.html#perform-a-find-request

You could also do a find directly on the Events table using your Person Key.

Also as a final note, if there is some sort of uncommitted record somewhere, from an API script call that doesn't finish with a commit, or otherwise, then the data may not be showing in the portal yet.

(Note answer edited with fresh information)

Comment: With respect, I don't think this is it.  First, it only took 10 minutes to have the data API return my result.  I just timed it.  Second, every time I refresh my app, it calls the database and reuses the token.  So it took 10 minutes of time, but my token was being used continuously, therefore resetting the clock to 15 minutes of token validity.  Third, regardless of if I remove a record via the data API or remove it manually through the web interface, the data API takes 10 minutes to give proper portal data, and the old PHP SDK gets the new record immediately.

Comment: Fourth, as mentioned, if I change the parent record holding the portal data at all, the data API will return a correct set of portal data immediately.

All of these things happened on the same token.  What you're suggesting may actually "work" but it's not ideal to have to delete a token used by an application which could have multiple concurrent users every time a record needs to update.  

Finally, this only seems to happen with portal data.  With field data, the data api has not had these issues.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "explicitly commit the record yourself".  It doesn't matter if I change the database via a script, or if I delete something via the FM web interface.  In any case, portaldata returned via a parent record takes 10 minutes to flush.

Comment: Record edits etc. made via the data API are not committed until an action occurs to commit or the session is closed. Ways around it is to simply close the session or call a script that will commit the record.  The PHP API would commit changes as they are made, the data API does not. If this is not the issue then it may be that the layout for that data API session has not refreshed, you could try calling a script via setting script.pre-request in your find request to refresh the layout.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that.  I've been using the data API for the past 9 months.  New records and updated records have been committed immediately when I use the methods at https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/17/en/dataapi/index.html#work-with-records_create-record and https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/17/en/dataapi/index.html#work-with-records_edit-record.

Comment: Also, what are you describing doesn't match what I am saying happens.  Given a layout, "Person", with a portal to layouts "Events":  if I update the Events table via the data API, the Person record (and it's portal data of Events) is immediately reflected in a call to the Person record via the PHP SDK.  It is not reflected in a call to the Person record via the data API until 10 minutes have passed, or until a change has been made to the Person record itself.

Comment: Apologies about the commit, you are right, I created an API code generator when the API first came out and have been using that.  The lack of commit happens in scripts!! The session will leave the script where it is and if there is no commit at the end of the script the record is still locked.  I will go back and edit my answers.

Comment: Just a final note, community.filemaker.com really is the best place to get FileMaker answers. I love stack overflow, but the filemaker community is thriving over there, not so much here.

Comment: Ok, thanks!  I'm relatively new to FM.  I'll start posting there, or maybe cross-posting to that forum.  Cheers!